# How do I multiply this in C?

Tags: c, precision, multiplication

I was writing a program which takes an input in dollars from the user and converts it to int which are the cents.
The user will always enter either an int or a floating point number with a maximum of 2 decimal places. I want to convert it to int by multiplying by 100. However the program doesn't work for some of the numbers.

```
int cents = (dollars*100);
```

`dollars` is the floating point input that the user gives. For example, If I `dollars` = 4.2, `cents` becomes 419.999. How can I correct this problem?

Comment: use a big integer type like `long cents` to store the entire total (e.g. $14000.99 is 1400099 cents) and just print explicitly dollars and cents whenever you print. E.g. `long cents = 1400099; printf("You've got $%ld.%02ld\n", cents/100, cents%100);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple adjust the value like this:

```
int cents = (int)(dollars*100 + 0.5);
```

Comment: Why do you arbtitrarily add 0.5? Do you want the bank to lose money

Answer (score 4):

You can't correct it.  Floating point numbers don't have "decimal places."  They are always approximate and fuzzy.  Don't ever use floating point numbers for money, ever -- this is one of the most important rules of software that deals with anything financial.  Read the input in as a string (`%s`), and put together the cents by finding the decimal point in the string and then using `atoi` on the parts before and after the `.`

Comment: +1 Agreed. But in practice I never have seen anyone using anything else than doubles for calculations done in the insurance sector. In my company it's even a written requirement. With all the problems this leads to...

Comment: @Axel why aren't you using a specialized class for handling money and simply make using *that* the requirement for handling the money. It's called separation of concerns

Comment: The requirement is to use the machine double precision data type. Implementing a specialized class that does everything just like double just would introduce overhead.

Comment: And people ask why COBOL is still around.  This is exactly the stuff COBOL (which used to be used everywhere in the insurance sector) is fantastic with.  I wonder if whoever wrote your company's requirement didn't understand what they were giving up when they moved from PIC specifiers (i.e. fixed decimal) to doubles when the company changed languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
cents = (int)((dollars*100) + .5);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can probably adjust your floating point precision model in your project properties
2) When converting from float to int it's always handy to add a bit to allow a round-down:

```
int cents = ((dollars*100.0)+0.5);
```